# remove element from array matlab

Tags: matlab

i have a array that contains all the files in a particular directory. I want to remove all the file entries that end with the .txt extension. This is what i have written

```
function fileList = removeElements(fileArray)    

    for idx = 1:numel(fileArray)

    if  (strfind(fileArray(idx),'.txt')  > 0 ) 
    display('XX');
    fileArray(idx) =[];
    end     

    end      

end
```

but i get a error

```
??? Undefined function or method 'gt' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
    Error in ==> removeElements at 6
        if( strfind(fileArray(idx),'.bmp')  > 0 )
```

can someone please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>0` is wrong in this case. Use `~isempty(strfind(....))` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the function and for-loop with the single line construction

```
% strip-out all '.txt' filenames
newList = oldList(cellfun(@(c)(isempty(strfind('.txt',c))),oldList));
```

The isempty() construction returns true if the filename does **not** include '.txt'. The oldList(...) construction returns a cell array of elements of oldList for which the isempty construction returns true.